# How Main() method of the internal class is called outside the assembly by CLR?

Tags: c#

If internal class can only be accessed by anywhere in same assembly and it can't be accessed outside the assembly how Main() method is called by CLR?

```
using System;

namespace  test
{
     internal class Program {
        public static void Main(String[] args){
            Console.WriteLine("Testing Internal Modifier!!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: They are marked by the compiler as 'entrypoint'. The CLR can just do "whatever it wants", within bounds. (http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf - II.15.4.1.2, page 181)

Comment: This is clearly a special, since CLR is not bound by the same rules when it executes the code I assume

Comment: Anything can be accessed anywhere via reflection and other methods, but in standard code it would be inaccessible

Comment: The CLR isn't written in C# and is not bound by the rules of C#, or even the rules of .NET (except insofar as it has to make programs run with the expected semantics in order to be useful). If it was Judge Dredd, it would be shouting "I *am* the law".

Comment: It is the C# compiler that sets the assembly's entrypoint, the CLR just calls it and doesn't care how it is declared and what it does.  It is the C# compiler that complains when you forget to write Main() or have more than one. It is also the one that *could* complain when it isn't public.  But they decided not to.  For a pretty good reason, arguably it *should* be private because nothing good can happen when other code also calls Main().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private, protected, internal etc. modifiers are there to keep your code clean and help you make less errors. Other than that, everything is still callable, those modifiers are in no way a security tool to prevent the CLR or even other code from calling your code.

Using reflection you can call every single method in your class, be it private, internal or public. You can even declare Main() as private, it'll still be the entry point to your application.